# (Already resolved)The discord bot does not display the welcome message in discord, but it did not receive any errors

Tags: python, discord.py

I write a discord bot to display welcome and leave messages, but when I enable it to send messages when someone enters the guild, it does not display the welcome message.

```py
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '[')
    
    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(" Bot is Online!")
    
    @bot.event
    async def on_member_join(member):
        channel = bot.get_channel(Token)
        
        await channel.send("{member}welcome to join!")
    
    @bot.event
    async def on_member_remove(member):
        channel = bot.get_channel(Token)
        await channel.send("{member} is leave the guild!")
    
    bot.run('Token')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ID of the channel, not the TOKEN of the bot.

```py
channel = bot.get_channel(channelid)
```